# how to achieve the same backgroud effect like the volume mixer?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys, I'm trying to do a form like the volume mixer.

Thanks to this link [create a form with a border but no title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594086/how-to-create-a-form-with-a-border-but-no-title-bar-like-volume-control-on-win), I'm half way done :) the form has white background (I assume its Window color), under it there is a line with a shadow and then a green like background (assuming InactiveBorder color).

I also found this: [c volume mixer like buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083245/c-volume-mixer-like-buttons-combo-boxes) where they suggest to use WPF for the button like effect.

My question will be, how to achieve the same background effect like the volume mixer in windows forms, with the gradient line?

Ty so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LinearGradientBrush gives you the functionality you need.  A quick sample below:

```
var startColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 245, 251);
var endColor = Color.FromArgb(204, 217, 234);

using (var brGradient = new LinearGradientBrush(panel1.ClientRectangle, startColor, endColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
{
    brGradient.Blend = new Blend
            {
                Factors = new[] { 1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f },
                Positions = new[] { 0.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f }
            };
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brGradient, panel1.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer, but what i want to achieve is the background of the form. If you see it its most white (window background) and then there is a line with a shadow and then there is some little "green" like background.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  Updated the answer (assuming I understand better now)

Comment: Ty so much, it really worked, just a little question about your solutions. the green color its a custom color not a system color right?